# Can the os x app connect with a device of bluetooth v2.0 through CoreBluetooth?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'm new in OS X development, I want to create an app to connect with a device via Bluetooth, but the device has bluetooth v2.0. My question is if is possible connect with it using CoreBluetooth.framework? If the answer is no, how can I to do that?. Thank you so much.

I'm so sorry for my English, it's so bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreBluetooth can only be used for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). You would need to look into the IOBluetooth framework which supports Bluetooth Classic: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/